# Localizing ABAddressBook

Tags: ios, localization, contacts, abaddressbook

I have an address book-based app where I grab the contacts name and display them in a table, just like ABPeopleViewController, using

```
NSString *name = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyCompositeName([contacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]);
aCell.textLabel.text = name;
[name release];
```

That works fine when I'm dealing with English names; they come out like this, as I want them to:

```
John Smith  (good)
Jane Doe    (good)
Taro Tanaka (Actually 太郎田中, and meh)
```

The last one, in Japanese, should ideally be Tanaka Taro.

When I changed the language to Chinese and Japanese instead, however, this is what I get:

```
Smith John   (bad)
Doe Jane     (bad)
Tanaka Taro  (田中太郎， good)
```

While what I want for all language settings is:

```
John Smith
Jane Doe
Tanaka Taro  (田中太郎, that is)
```

Apple's built-in contacts deals with this by boldfacing the **last name**, but that seems crude for an international user. Is there anyway of detecting language and displaying the name accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, after a bit of digging I found the answer in iOS 5's new NSLinguisticTagger, which can do all sorts of wonderous things with language and strings. With a little manipulation it can be coerced to tell me what language a string is in and therefore how to put together a full name. The answer I posted in another question since it's leaking memory and I cannot solve it. Here's the link:

[NSLinguisticTagger Memory Leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707521/nslinguistictagger-memory-leak)